# Make Golang graphql query without adding string

Tags: go, graphql

If I "declare" a request in one swoop like this, it works:

```
payload := strings.NewReader(`query {
        node(id: "gid://shopify/BulkOperation/2000000011111") {
          ... on BulkOperation {
                url
                partialDataUrl
                }
            }
        }`)
```

However, the `gid` field is changing, so I cannot hard-code it like above. So I did the following (`queryId` is a variable):

```
s := `query {
        node(id: "` + queryId + `") {
          ... on BulkOperation {
                url
                partialDataUrl
                }
            }
        }`

    client := &http.Client{}
    req, err := http.NewRequest(method, url, strings.NewReader(s))
```

And the result is not correct, compared to when I hard code it. Seems like the `gid` was not added in properly, resulting in empty reponse.

The original Python code is:

```
data_query = '''
    query {
      node(id: "%s") {
        ... on BulkOperation {
          url
          partialDataUrl
        }
      }
    }
    ''' % bulkopr_id
```

Comment: It does contain what I think to be right. I printed out the payload, pasted it in Postman the the response was correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Discover the problem: Shopify needs a little time to prepare the query result. In my code I call the API too quickly after it was generated, therefore the result is empty. Simply put `time.Sleep(3*time.Second)` and the response will not be empty.